# virtualenv versus setup.py install --user

Tags: python

I'm using setuptools, and I am running with virtualenv. When I try to install --user, I get problems:

1. a complaint that .pth files are not supported
2. it seems to be installing outside the virtualenv

Should I just flush the use of --user since I'm in a virtualenv?

```
exec ../virtualenv/target/vroot/bin/python setup.py install --user
running install
Checking .pth file support in /Users/benson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
/Users/benson/x/ws-client-bindings/python/setup/../virtualenv/target/vroot/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /Users/benson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [user directory](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) is part of Python, not virtualenv.  Packages installed to user will look like system packages (they will be available outside a virtualenv).  So it is not a solution for isolating package requirements and versions for a specific application.

The standard procedure is to activate a virtualenv and use install without the --user option.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would recommend dropping that usage pattern and install everything using *pip* invoked directly from the `bin` directory of your *virtualenv*. I find absolute paths when installing/running from a *virtualenv* is best, since in that case there's never any question as to exactly which one it's using.

You can then keep track (say, in source control) of the *requirements* files for each of your *virtualenv*s (via `pip freeze > requirements`) so they can be created elsewhere quickly.